# IBM XMS .NET remove RFH2 header / set target client does not work

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

We develop an .NET application which connects to IBM MQ with IBM XMS library.
It's working, but the produced messages contains the MQRFH2 header, which the target application cannot process, so we have to remove it.
This normally can be done by set a property like https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=definitions-xmsc-wmq-target-client.
We tried this by setting `cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);`

```
                IBM.XMS.IConnection connectionWMQ;
                IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory;
                IBM.XMS.IConnectionFactory cf;

                factoryFactory = IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(IBM.XMS.XMSC.CT_WMQ);
                cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

                cf.SetStringProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, mqQueueOptions.HostName);
                cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_PORT, mqQueueOptions.Port);
                cf.SetStringProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, mqQueueOptions.Channel);
                cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                cf.SetStringProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, mqQueueOptions.QueueManager);
                cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
                cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);
                cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);
```

But then we get:

```
Retry 00:00:02 of RetryPolicy-1d242dc3 at , due to: 'IBM.XMS.XMSException: Value 1 not valid for property: targetClient
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsPropertyContextImpl.SetObjectPropertyInternal(String name, Object value, Boolean validationEnabled)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsPropertyContextImpl.SetObjectProperty(String name, Object value)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsPropertyContextImpl.SetIntProperty(String name, Int32 value)
```

What's the problem?

Tried by setting `cf.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);` to remove the RF2H header but get exception of invalid value for the property.

Comment: How do you open your queue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an MQ/XMS equivalent for the MQ/JMS setTargetClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767479/is-there-an-mq-xms-equivalent-for-the-mq-jms-settargetclient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a roundabout way this question is a duplicate of [Is there an MQ/XMS equivalent for the MQ/JMS setTargetClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767479/is-there-an-mq-xms-equivalent-for-the-mq-jms-settargetclient)

In Summary

You are setting the property on the connection factory. It needs to set it on the destination. Same syntax as you have, but somewhere later in the code when you have instantiated a `destination` object.

```cs
destination.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);
```

See: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=definitions-xmsc-wmq-target-client

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I get it to work, by setting the property on the destination

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, based on what JMS does, that should have worked.

My next thought would be to set it on the Destination object and not for the connection object.

FYI:

```
targetClient=0 means it is sending a JMS message
targetClient=1 means it is sending an MQ message (non-JMS)
```

So, did you try setting the property as a boolean?

i.e.

```
cf.SetBooleanProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, true);
```